# Output node.type in page.html.twig gives "EntityReferenceFieldItemList cannot be printed"

Tags: theming, 8

Not sure if this is a bug, but I wanted to add some debug into an HTML comment in my `page.html.twig` file. I added `<!-- type={{node.type}} -->` but I get:

```
Uncaught PHP Exception Exception: "Object of type Drupal\Core\Field\EntityReferenceFieldItemList cannot be printed." at /www/cn8/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Template/TwigExtension.php line 443
```

It took me a while to track down since I was sure this would work. Shouldn't EntityReferenceFieldItemList have a toString() function for this purpose?

Comment: I just worked out that I can write ``node.type.target_id`` and get the content type as a string, but still don't understand why ``node.type`` doesn't output something, but crashes...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`node.type` is a reference to the node type entity. You can get the id of the content type with `target_id`, as you have mentioned in the comment. For debugging this might be OK, but most times you want to get the label, which is nicely formatted and translatable:

```
{{ node.type.entity.label }}
```

Comment: Thanks again! How do you know this stuff? :)

Comment: @Nic You just read the source, it's all there :)

Comment: Which class though? Drupal\Core\Entity\Plugin\DataType\EntityReference ?